# How to transfer domain to IIS in Azure with EPP Code?

Tags: azure, dns, windows-server, epp

I have an old website I'm trying to move to an Azure Virtual Machine (Windows 10 Server). My old service gave me an EPP Code and unlocked the domain, but after hours of research I couldn't find anything that told me how to transfer it to the server.

Comment: AFAIK, if you want to move a website to Azure VM, you only need to [host your website on Azure VM using IIS](https://newhelptech.wordpress.com/2017/12/19/step-by-step-how-to-hosting-website-on-azure-vm-using-iis-in-microsoft-azure/). Open websites ports on NSG attached to the subnet where the VM resides. It seems that you do not need to transfer the domain to Azure, let me know if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Domains can only be transferred amongst Domain registrars. Microsoft or you VM is not a Domain registrar so you cannot transfer to either.

You can set record on current domain registrar to point to your VM or website hosted in VM like article in comment mentions.

If you are trying to manage everything on the azure portal you can make use of [Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-overview).  This will make it easier to assign domain to azure resources, just be aware there is a cost to it. You can follow [this article to host you domain in Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns).

Hope this helps.